# Pick up vs. pick up on

Tags: prepositions

What is the difference between pick up and pick up on?

The phrases for consideration (from a book):

> - our brains pick up on the underlying patterns
> - I can pick up the telltale signs
> - you start picking up hints about people

The meaning is the same (notice, catch), but in the first phrase "on" is used.

Comment: These phrases are quotes from the book...

Answer (score 1):

They're similar metaphorical uses of "pick," but "pick up on" has more the sense of "notice something hidden or implied" (as a pattern can be implied by information), whereas "pick up" implies a more straightforward type of learning. For example: "She found that she could pick up new programming languages more quickly once she had already learned several of them"; "He picked up on the important details of what I was saying and was able to extend my logic even farther."

"Pick" by itself means simply "select," so the alternative suggestion "pick the problem" (though possible) has a different meaning: "On the test, students were asked to pick a problem from a set of three options and answer it within five minutes." "Pick" is an old word and so has developed many uses with different prepositions and meanings: pick at, pick over, etc.

Comment: Nothing incorrect here, but I think it might be worth emphasising that whereas *to pick up X* usually implies *to **learn** X (and thus be able to **use** it*, the more oblique form *to pick up **on** X* often specifically limits the meaning to *to learn **of the existence of** X*. Thus, in [*He picked up **on** the use of English within conversational Swedish*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22Swedish+is+increasingly+interspersed+with+English%22), the implication is simply that he ***noticed** this tendency*. But without ***on***, it implies ***he adopted the same habit himself***.